# HSQL default identity 0 conflicts with jpa entities with identity int id defaulted to 0

Tags: jpa, testing, hsqldb, auto-increment, entitymanager

I have a JPA entity with:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "INT")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

and using `EntityManager.merge` by default

For testing I'm using HSQL that default its "auto increment" setting to 0

whenever I create a new object, my default int id will be set to 0, and the merge operation, instead of inserting the object as a new record,  will update it instead.

any idea how to solve this?

One option I tried without success is to set the default "auto increment" of HSQL to 1 (not altering a specific column using RESTART)

thanks!

Comment: The auto increment default is 1. It is the "START WITH" default which is 0. You need to change this.

Comment: to isolate tests I use "TRUNCATE SCHEMA PUBLIC RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT NO CHECK" before each test. Why isn't it restarting with the default of 1?